# Blank white space on top of the webpage

Tags: php, html, css, smarty, template-engine

What could the possible cause blank space on top of the page

I want to provide photo for clarification but due to low reputation in stackoverflow I couldn't upload it. I am using Smarty as php template engine.

```
<html>
    <head>
        {include file="_js.tpl"}
        <title>{$title|escape}</title>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        {literal}
            <style type="text/css">
                body{
                    margin:0;
                    padding:0;
                    display: block;
                    font-family: arial;
                }

                #main_iframe 
                {
                    position: relative;
                    width: 100%;
                    height:665px;
                    border:0px;         
                }

                #iframe_setting{
                    padding-left: 220px;
                    background: url('{/literal}{$vir_img}{literal}background.png');
                }
                #content-wrapper{
                    height: 665px;
                    padding-left: 10px;

                }

            </style>

            <script type="text/javascript">
                $(document).ready(function(){
                    $("button#logout").click(function(){
                        window.location = "{/literal}{$url_app}{literal}?m=account&c=do_logout";
                    });

                });

                function go(loc)
                {
                    document.getElementById('main_iframe').src=loc;
                }

                function go3(loc)
                {
                    document.getElementById('iframeid').src=loc;
                }
            </script>
        {/literal}
    </head>
        <body>{include file="header.tpl"}
                <div style="position:absolute;z-index: 999;">
                    {include file="sidebar.tpl"}
                </div>
                    <div id="iframe_setting">
                        <div id="content-wrapper">
                            {$content}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    {include file="footer.tpl"}
        </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please post the rendered HTML. You can include a link to your image and someone with enough rep can embed it.

Comment: you can use any css reset available. just google "css reset" or you can do body, html {margin:0; padding:0; }

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/htvxc9vkm45bryn/Screenshot%20from%202013-05-10%2010%3A46%3A05.png

Comment: You would really have to show us the HTML as it is rendered in the browser (View source or something like that), not the HTML before it goes through the templating engine. For all I know this templating engine could be turning the whole website upside down.

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/0j8ouv8zaaqxo9l/sample.zip
i have rendered the file as you said. u can download it from my drop box

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/), make sure that all the files included in this file, as well as itself, are "Encode in UTF-8 without BOM". To do so, follow as below:

In Notpad++ -> (menu) Encoding -> (click) Encode in UTF-8 without BOM

This usually happens if you have used UTF8 characters and saved the file as UTF8. Then, there will be three invisible characters which causes that white space.